# Folder is not showing the most recent thumbnails of the files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

A few days ago I noticed that folder's preview is not being updated with the newest thumbnails of files that are created there.

Is there a reason why it seems to be so random? And is there a way how to force it to update?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yeah you need to clear the thumbnail cache https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+clear+the+thumbnail+cache

Comment: I already did that but for some reason it still is not being updated properly. Also I find it a bit pointless to clear thumbnail cache cuz Windows will still have to generate them again which just slows down the PC. Is there a way how to increase cache size? Perhaps it will solve the issue.

Comment: https://winaero.com/change-icon-cache-size-windows-10/